# 500 Error: "End of script output before headers" - Simple script within Wordpress theme

Tags: php, http-headers, 500-error

I have a multi-site install of Wordpress running fine on a unmanaged CentOS server, however for a certain feature I need to do my own thing on certain pages and manually interact with some non-Wordpress tables.

When writing the script for the form actions, I've been getting a 500: Internal Server Error. Which according to the Apache logs is due to "end of script output before headers".

To check it wasn't just me doing something ridiculous, I tried just directly linking to the file and changing it to `<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>`, but the issue has persisted. So it can't be an issue with the script itself.

Wordpress not having any issues implies it isn't necessarily PHP itself either...

I've tried Google-ing and trawling through here, but I can't seem to find a useful answers. Any help would be very welcomed. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but from what I remember, and what it sounds like you need to do is - at the beginning of your script [check to see if the headers have been sent](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) and send them if not.

That's assuming you aren't using the [WordPress API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) and just rolling your own script that is being called for some reason.

Comment: Attempting to check to see if the headers have been sent didn't seem to help :/ Thank you for the response though

Comment: You would normally only need to "check to see if the headers have been sent" in case you needed to set an _additional_ header (eg. a cookie). (Because attempting to set a header after the headers have already been sent would result in an E_WARNING.)